# Arch, Gnome - how to change the default terminal?

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, gnome, terminal-emulator

I want to change my default terminal emulator, that is, the terminal that opens when I `Right Click` -> `Open in terminal`

So far, I've tried:

- `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`
- `sudo update-alternatives --config $TERM` (`$TERM` is equal to xterm-256color)
- changing the `TERM` variable in `~/.bashrc`
- chaning the default terminal in GNOME settings - however, there was no option to choose a default terminal emulator, only for the default browser, media player, etc

Answer (score 1):

Try this command: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec <your-terminal-here>`

Comment: I'm afraid this information is already outdated ! GNOME 43.2 doesn't use those settings anymore, and I wasn't able to replace them.

Comment: See [this thread](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/default-terminal/1307) to get more information.